# How would I return only specific values from a comma separated column entry in HIVEQL?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

So I have a table which contains a column where each entry is a comma separated list. See below:

| ID | class | dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 08 | A,B,C,D | 20220801 |
| 21 | A,B,C,D,E,F,G | 20220801 |
| 92 | A,B,C | 20220801 |
| 98 | A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H | 20220801 |

In the actual table, some of the class entries contain up to 232 different elements.

I'd like to return only specific values in a new column with the same comma separated format. So as an example from the above, I'd like ID 21 to return a column with 'C,D,E'.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of problems.

Comment: Agreed. Unfortunately this isn't my table, I'm simply having to work with it.

Comment: how or based onw hat logic you want to pick C,D,E ? You can always use substr().

Comment: It would be based on whether the class entry contained a specific string. The filter would not change based on entry. Each entry can differ a fair amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try below query which returns class entries matching with any of **C,D,E** from each row.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 08 ID, 'A,B,C,D' class, '20220801' dt UNION ALL
  SELECT 21, 'A,B,C,D,E,F,G', '20220801' UNION ALL
  SELECT 92, 'A,B,C', '20220801' UNION ALL
  SELECT 98, 'A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H', '20220801'
)
SELECT ID, dt, CONCAT_WS(',', collect_list(cls)) clz
  FROM sample_table t LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(SPLIT(class, ',')) c AS cls
 WHERE cls IN ('C', 'D', 'E')
 GROUP BY ID, dt;
```

###### Query results

[image]